# Nvidia drivers crash

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers for MX150 card in Lenovo IdeaPad 320, but after the installation (I have tried many ways - installing using repositories, run file and Software & Updates, but no one works) and system reboot I see this message (it has been spamming this message for several seconds and then stopped like that) and I cannot to do anything.

PS.: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

Thanks for help in advance!

[Error message - PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEaro.jpg)

Comment: MX150 is very new and there are only two driver version supporting it. Which version have you installed exactly and how exactly did you tried to install the drivers? Saying "tried many ways" means nothing and it's useless. When asking please always describe what you did in order to avoid duplicated suggestions and wasting your and others time.

Comment: Yeah, I see there are 2 versions of this driver. I have tried to install 384.98 from 1. Terminal using apt-get install nvidia-384 2. RUN file (what didn't work) 3. Software & Updates. I have also tried to install the second version - 387.22 - (it appeared this morning) using Software & Updates too and the result has been the same.

Comment: If that is the only thing you did it should work. But, of course, it wasn't... Try again but this time purge all nvidia drivers before attempting to install again at Additional Drivers: `sudo apt purge nvidia*`

Comment: I have been purging all nvidia drivers every time I have been repairing my system after this crash.